# Load different script if used in SidebarWidget and different within POST

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've been searching all over to find a way to render different style / script when my shortcode is used within POST and different style/script when used in Sidebar widget.

The idea is to achieve different size for the gallery. I am running jquery on #mygallery id

So here is what I tried doing

```
            if ( is_dynamic_sidebar() ) { ?>
        <ul id="widgetGallery">
        <?php }else{ ?>
        <ul id="myGallery">
        <?php }
```

But this does not help me because what it does, it checks if I have my gallery widget in sidebar, if yes, it renders "WidgetGallery" ID for UL .. but it screws up the gallery within post and runs the same "WidgetGallery" ID on that too.

I have tried using the following with no avail

is_active_sidebar
is_active_widget
is_main_query
is_dynamic_sidebar

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Found it .. I had to use

```
        <?php if (in_the_loop() ) { ?>
```